# How can I compare two groups security permissions?

Tags: powershell, acl

I am trying to compare two security groups from Active Directory and I want to see the rights and figure out the differences.

I have been trying some get-acl but can't seem to find the best way to compare and output.

Comment: Please clarify if you are comparing two Active Directory groups e.g. use `Get-ADGroup` and `Get-ADGroupMember`. `Get-Acl` is for folder permissions not Active Directory permissions.

Comment: @HAL9256 I am trying to compare two security groups that are within the same OU.

Answer (score 0):

Get-ACL will be used to compare groups in folder.

If I understand correctly, you would like to compare un security group in Active Directory to an another one ?

You could try by exporting both groups in a CSV with

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -eq "Insert group name here"} | Get-ADGroupMember |  select Name | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Test.csv"
```

Do that for both groups (2 CSV) and use the compare-object 
Link : [Link to Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-6)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

One easy way to look at differences would be to use `Out-Gridview` to do a quick stare and compare.

```
"GroupName1","GroupName1" | Foreach-Object {
    Get-ADGroup $_ -Properties * 
} | Out-Gridview
```

Or, you can assign both groups to variables and use the Compare-Object cmdlet

```
$group1 = Get-ADGroup "GroupName1" -Properties * 
$group2 = Get-ADGroup "GroupName2" -Properties * 

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $group1 -DifferenceObject $group2 -Property memberof
```